# Ellipsize within word possible?

Tags: android, textview

I have a list of items where the words may be longer then the width of the textView. I would like the text to be ellipsized.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:text="* SomeVeryLongWordWhichIsLongerThanWidth" />
```

The problem is, that the output is `*...` instead of `* SomeVeryLongWordWhi...`. How can I achieve the latter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `\u00A0` instead of normal space sign
`\u00A0` its non-breakable space

`android:text="*\u00A0SomeVeryLongWordWhichIsLongerThanWidth"`